# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes when some apps are opened

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, 20.04, freeze, reboot

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, Ubuntu freezes when chrome is opened. So I had to restart my laptop every time this happens. And the problem is solved when on restart and Chrome works fine after that.

Everything worked fine when in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is quite a trend at the moment, and I believe this may be a fault with the way Chromium or Ubuntu 20.04 is operating. I have seen a plethora of the same concerns raised, and at this point in time, the only thing I can suggest is perhaps see if the [Chromium Bug Threads](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=ubuntu%2020.04&can=1) have any information.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the non working apps need to be updated for their v20.04 compatible ones. Some changes between Ubuntu versions might affect the apps that was made for v18.04.

Even some shell (terminal) commands might be different between versions. Try to uninstall the non working apps. Clean the apps catalogs. Reinstall the new ones, check the apps description if it should work in the v20.04.

**Update Applications**

To update the applications, just perform `sudo apt upgrade -y`; if you read `man apt` you can also specify a command to auto-remove packages that are not compatible.

Comment: Perhaps expand on the commands and methods here. FWIW I am seeing a trend with Chromium being a pain on 20.04LTS, so if another question answers this, I'd refer to it.